# SQL Use Column Value as Keyword in Query String

Tags: mysql, sql, expression, keyword

Ok so here is the example query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, amount FROM tbl_recurring_payment AS t 
WHERE ADDDATE(t.start_date,  INTERVAL (t.period) UPPER(t.unit)) = CURDATE());
```

The area in question is UPPER(t.unit)  where I want that expr to be treated as a mysql keyword (possible values of this column are day, week, month, year).  It throws an error since it cant use the expr as a keyword.  Is there anything I can do to get this to work or should I just  add a check for the unit and hardcode the keyword for each possible value of unit?

Comment: you can edit your question after posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really just need to know if its possible to use an column value as a keyword in a query string

NO

Comment: @Ypercube, there is a place and a time for dynamic SQL, this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, my thought is that I would approach this with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT    -- Is the DISTINCT really necessary???
    id,
    amount
FROM
    tbl_recurring_payment AS T
WHERE
    CASE t.unit
        WHEN 'YEAR' THEN ADDDATE(t.start_date, INTERVAL t.period YEAR)
        ...
    END = CURDATE()
```

You might be able to streamline the code a bit (for readability, not performance) by using the `INTERVAL` syntax without `ADDDATE`, but I don't use MySQL enough to know if that's possible. (`...t.start_date + CASE t.unit WHEN 'YEAR' THEN INTERVAL t.period YEAR...`)?

Comment: well its not really a question of how to write the query, the question is really what it says in the title,  The script was just to give some context.  I really just need to know if its possible to use a column value as a keyword in a query string

Comment: None that I am aware of without using dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL of course has its own drawbacks.