# Variable in the query

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
UPDATE ost_timeblock 
SET 
  timeblock_due_date=DATE(timeblock_next_update),
  timeblock_next_update=DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time **timeblock_recurrence_unit** )
WHERE timeblock_recurrence=1 
  AND timeblock_complete=0 
  AND timeblock_next_update=FROM_UNIXTIME(1337662800)
```

when i use manual day or month as `timeblock_recurrence_unit` it works fine.

`timeblock_recurrence_unit = enum(day,month,year)` i want value of `timeblock_recurrence_unit` at above bold location

Is there any way to do it with cases.

```
If timeblock_recurrence_unit = 'day' then 
timeblock_next_update=DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time day )

If timeblock_recurrence_unit = 'month' then  
timeblock_next_update=DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time month)
```

Comment: please format your query that it fits in several lines

Comment: I refer the honourable gentleman to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749892/sql-use-column-value-as-keyword-in-query-string). Unfortunately, it's just not possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ost_timeblock SET 
    timeblock_due_date = DATE(timeblock_next_update),
    timeblock_next_update = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time      
**timeblock_recurrence_unit** )
WHERE 
    timeblock_recurrence=1 
AND timeblock_complete=0 
AND timeblock_next_update = FROM_UNIXTIME(1337662800)
```

According to mysql doc: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

The date_add feature accepts an inverval of dates and a unit, to perform dates arithmetic.
You have to provide a given unit, not an ENUM of units like you would like to do.

You will have to revise your functional requirements and maybe think again whether the DATE_ADD method is performing the wanted action.

rgds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use user define variable as follows;
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

```
SET @timeblock_recurrence_unit = 'DAY';
UPDATE ost_timeblock SET
 timeblock_due_date=DATE(timeblock_next_update),
 timeblock_next_update=DATE_ADD(
       NOW(),
       INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time @timeblock_recurrence_unit
 ) WHERE 
    timeblock_recurrence=1 AND 
    timeblock_complete=0 AND
    timeblock_next_update= FROM_UNIXTIME(1337662800);
```

Comment: @user1410812, see the comment by DaveRandom above. That simply won't work, you can't use a variable for the unit, it has to be a constant.